# Clone all drive partitions?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I've got a Dell desktop computer with a small SATA hard drive.

That drive has got two partitions: C and D.  The `D:\` is a recovery partition that can be used to return the machine to its factory default condition.

I'd like to replace that old small hard drive with a new large hard drive.  I also want to preserve the recovery partition.

How can I clone the small drive to the large one--partitions and all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the opensource (and free) software called [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)

It has a bit by bit cloning tool that will do exactly what you want.

You can then use GParted to increase the size of your C: partition.

Answer (score 4):

Just did this last night with [Easeus Disk Copy v2.0](http://www.easeus.com/disk-copy/). They also offer a freeware application to resize the partition after you've copied to the new drive. Just download the .iso for DC2, burn to a disk and reboot with both drives installed and boot to the CD. It uses a full on GUI with mouse support.

EASEUS Partition Master Home Edition will allow you to resize your current partitions without destroying the data. After its installed just click, drag and reboot and you're done.

The entire process took maybe 40 minutes last night. Easiest thing evar.

Answer (score 1):

use clonezilla, carbon copy or symantec ghost to make a clone of the drive onto a similiar or bigger size hard drive. Be very carefull because if you make the source drive as target, you will lose all your data and will need the help of a data recovery professional. So take great caution.